# Angular promise inside promise?

Tags: angular

I have a function like this:

```
resulta = 0;
resultb = 0;
resultc = 0;
resultd = 0;
    
    var wait = new promise((resolve, reject) => {
        data.forEach((single,index,array) =>{
            if (single.a == '1'){this.resulta = '1'}
            else if (single.a=='2') {this.resultb = '2'}
            else if (single.a=='3'){this.resultc = '3'}
            else if (single.a=='4'){
                this.function(single.a).then(async (bs) => {
                    if (somecondition) {
                        await bs.forEach(b => {
                            this.ccount = 0;
                            if(condition === true){
                                this.c = 'yes';
                                this.ccount = this.ccount +1;                      
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if(this.ccount > 0){
                        this.resultd = '4';
                    }
                    else {
                       this.resultd = 'N/A';
                    }
                }
            }
            if (index === array.length -1)resolve();
        });
    });
    wait.then(async()=>{
        console.log('count', this.count); // always is 0 but it should be something > 0
        console.log('resulta', this.resulta); // 1 as it should be
        console.log('resultb', this.resultb); // 2 as it should be
        console.log('resultc', this.resultc); // 3 as it should be
        console.log('resultd', this.resultd); // 0 and it should be or 4 or N/A
    });
```

so the problem here is that the first foreach ends before the 2nd foreach so its resolve the promise, how can i wait for the second foreach (inside the latest else if) to finish before it ends the first foreach?

Comment: Btw: [`forEach` does not wait for promises.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: You have tagged this as `angular`. I would consider using `Observables` rather than `promises` in angular

Comment: The same opinion as @Owen, you can use Subscription or Observable instead of promises in angular, use rxjs please <3

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking promises should work well in forEach block. No it does not happen in that way. You have to make sure that your inner promise should be return returned properly. Then you can create a promises array, and by using `Promise.all` you can check whether all promises are finished or not.

**Code**

```
const promises = data.map((single,index,array) =>{
    if (single.a == '1'){ return this.resulta = '1' }
    else if (single.a=='2') {return this.resultb = '2' }
    else if (single.a=='3'){ return this.resultc = '3' }
    else if (single.a=='4') {
        return this.function(single.a).then((bs) => {
            if (somecondition) {
                bs.forEach(b => {
                    this.ccount = 0;
                    if(condition === true){
                        this.c = 'yes';
                        this.ccount = this.ccount +1;                      
                    }
                });
            }
            if(this.ccount > 0){
                this.resultd = '4';
            }
            else {
               this.resultd = 'N/A';
            }
        }
    }
});

Promise.all(promises).then(async()=>{
    console.log('count', this.count);
    console.log('resulta', this.resulta);
    console.log('resultb', this.resultb);
    console.log('resultc', this.resultc);
    console.log('resultd', this.resultd);
});
```